# Remove a string from an URL and redirect to it

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to remove a string from an URL and redirect to it

URL examples

```
www.domain.com/document/this-page1/subpage1/subpage2/
www.domain.com/document/that-page2/subpage1/subpage2/
```

Result I want

```
www.domain.com/document/page1/subpage1/subpage2/
www.domain.com/document/page2/subpage1/subpage2/
```

I tried something like this but don't worked

```
RewriteRule ^this-/(.*) /$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?document/this-(.+)$ /document/$1 [L]
```

If you want to redirect the client externally, then alter it slightly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?document/this-(.+)$ /document/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: this has no effect on my system

Comment: So then you need to answer a bunch of questions: 1. where and how did you implement those rules? 2. what does your http servers error log file say? 3. is the interpretation of dynamic configuration files enabled at all if you implemented the rules in such files?